# Neo4J OutOfMemory error when querying

Tags: neo4j

I've recently started working with Neo4J and so far I haven't been able to find an answer to the problems I'm having, in particular with the server. I'm using version 1.8.1 and running the server as a service on Windows, not embedded. The graph I have has around 7m nodes and nearly 11m relationships.

With small queries and multiples of, things run nicely. However, when I'm trying to pull back more complex queries, potentially thousands of rows, things go sour. If I'm using the console, I'll get nothing and then after a few minutes or more the word undefined appears (it's trying to do something in Javascript but I'm not sure what). If I'm using Neo4JClient in .NET, it'll time out (I'm working this through a WCF service) and I suspect my problems are server side.

Here is a sample cypher query that has caused me problems in the console:

```
start begin = node:idx(ID="1234")
MATCH begin-[r1?:RELATED_TO]-n1-[r2?:RELATED_TO]-n2-[r3?:RELATED_TO]-n3-[r4?:RELATED_TO]-n4
RETURN begin.Title?, r1.RelationType?, n1.Title?, r2.RelationType?, n2.Title?, r3.RelationType?, n3.Title?, r4.RelationType?, n4.Title?;
```

I've looked through the logs and I'm receiving the following severe error:

```
SEVERE: The exception contained within MappableContainerException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.StringWriter.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.PrintWriter.newLine(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.PrintWriter.println(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.PrintWriter.println(Unknown Source)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.PipeExecutionResult$$anonfun$dumpToString$1.apply(PipeExecutionResult.scala:96)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.PipeExecutionResult$$anonfun$dumpToString$1.apply(PipeExecutionResult.scala:96)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foreach(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:45)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.PipeExecutionResult.dumpToString(PipeExecutionResult.scala:96)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.PipeExecutionResult.dumpToString(PipeExecutionResult.scala:124)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.javacompat.ExecutionResult.toString(ExecutionResult.java:90)
    at org.neo4j.shell.kernel.apps.Start.exec(Start.java:72)
    at org.neo4j.shell.kernel.apps.ReadOnlyGraphDatabaseApp.execute(ReadOnlyGraphDatabaseApp.java:32)
    at org.neo4j.shell.impl.AbstractAppServer.interpretLine(AbstractAppServer.java:127)
    at org.neo4j.shell.kernel.GraphDatabaseShellServer.interpretLine(GraphDatabaseShellServer.java:92)
    at org.neo4j.shell.impl.AbstractClient.evaluate(AbstractClient.java:130)
    at org.neo4j.shell.impl.AbstractClient.evaluate(AbstractClient.java:114)
    at org.neo4j.server.webadmin.rest.ShellSession.evaluate(ShellSession.java:96)
    at org.neo4j.server.webadmin.rest.ConsoleService.exec(ConsoleService.java:123)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
```

From an educated guess perspective looking at the stack trace, is it that I'm pulling back too many records? Since it's running out of memory whilst expanding the StringBuffer.

I've wondered whether GC could be playing a part, so I got hold of GCViewer. It doesn't seem to be Garbage Collection, I can add in a screenshot from GCViewer if you think it will be useful.

I've allocated the JVM anywhere between the default value and 8G of memory. Here are some of my settings from my configuration files (I'll try and include only the relevant ones). Let me know if you need any more.

Neo4J.properties

```
# Default values for the low-level graph engine
use_memory_mapped_buffers=false

# Keep logical logs, helps debugging but uses more disk space, enabled for legacy reasons
keep_logical_logs=true
```

Neo4J-server.properties

```
# HTTP logging is disabled. HTTP logging can be enabled by setting this property to 'true'.
org.neo4j.server.http.log.enabled=false
```

Neo4J-Wrapper.conf (possibly inexpertly slotted together)

```
# Uncomment the following line to enable garbage collection logging
wrapper.java.additional.4=-Xloggc:data/log/neo4j-gc.log

# Setting a different Garbage Collector as recommended by Neo4J
wrapper.java.additional.5=-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC

# other beneficial settings that should boost performance
wrapper.java.additional.6=-d64
wrapper.java.additional.7=-server
wrapper.java.additional.8=-Xss1024k

# Initial Java Heap Size (in MB)
wrapper.java.initmemory=1024

# Maximum Java Heap Size (in MB)
wrapper.java.maxmemory=8000
```

Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to use result streaming? It could reduce the amount of buffering required. http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-streaming.html

Comment: @Louis, no, but from reading the section from the documentation if it were possible it might solve the issue. Is it possible to utilise streaming at all in webadmin? I'm going to guess it's not in Neo4JClient yet, since it mentions that it's new.

Comment: I can't provide a full answer, I only came across it in the documentation recently. An other alternative would be to use pagination to avoid building such a large resultset. I rarely see just increasing available memory as a long term solution.

Comment: I agree, though I did try increasing the memory to 8G (as it is now), but to no success, so it's not even a short term solution. Thanks for your pointers. If there's no better answer, I'll give pagination a shot until I can find a way of using streaming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your query is simply too complex. when you have such a large graph than to be sure you will not reach your heap memory limit, you must have appropriate memory allocated. you might want to play a little bit with this configuration:  [io examples](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/configuration-io-examples.html#configuration-batchinsert).

however, your query could be simplified to this:

```
start begin = node:idx(ID="1234")
MATCH p=begin-[r1:RELATED_TO*0..4]-n4
RETURN p
```

Comment: I'm using Windows and I believe Neo has a different way of handling memory mapping on Windows, allocating half of the heap space to memory mapping. In other words, would changing these settings have any effect? 
As to your query improvements, it definitely looks better, thanks, I'll try using paths for this particular query from now on.

Comment: i think neo4j memory handling is platform independent, since all the memory stuff is handled by java itself. depends on your java runtime environment, but as far as i know there should be no differences in heap mapping between OSs

Comment: I eventually ended up removing the line in neo4j.properties where I explicitly turned off memory mapping and reconfigured the mappings to this:

neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory=250M
neostore.relationshipstore.db.mapped_memory=500M
neostore.propertystore.db.mapped_memory=500M
neostore.propertystore.db.strings.mapped_memory=750M
neostore.propertystore.db.arrays.mapped_memory=0M

I'm going to mark this as the answer tentatively, since things seem to be better! I haven't been able to make the exception reappear at any rate. Does this mean though that Neo4J can't handle large result sets?

Comment: in case of result sets, maybe the restriction lies in the HTTP data transfer (when using REST or anything else). try to run that in pure ./neo4j-shell console on the server and see whether it outputs anything.

Comment: Argh! The errors have started appearing again. Also, from the queries we're running, I'm not sure the speeds are as blistering as I would've expected. 

I gave executing the commands locally on the shell a try. In 1.8 no real difference. I'm toying with the 1.9 milestone version, as it claims to be better and it at least doesn't throw any OutOfMemory errors, at least not yet.

Comment: Scratch that, the OutOfMemory errors do appear in 1.9 but very rarely. Hopefully it's a step in the right direction. I still need a way of getting back large result sets though.

Comment: using `LIMIT` and `SKIP` can help. simply run the same query several times, but at the and append `limit 100 skip 0` for the first run, `limit 100 skip 100` for the second run, etc etc till you dont get all results. you may try to find the highest limit number to run the query as less times as possible

Comment: Thanks, this is what I'll probably do to get around large result sets. Hopefully Neo4J will have better support for this in later versions.

Comment: in my opinion, that kind of support will never happen. the concept of graph db is used to match across huge amount of data and get some result. in case you are returnig too large result set, it might be against the whole graph db concept, since returning very large sets is almost the same as returning the whole db, and for that case you can simply use sql. but this is just my opinion as far as i understand neo4j, maybe the guys from neology will give you precise answer.

Comment: I disagree that it's against the graph database ethos. What I'm essentially trying to do is find all nearby and mid-ranged nodes from a starting node. An SQL like SELECT * isn't what I'm trying to do here. I know at least that SQL Server streams the results back to the client as soon as it finds them. So maybe as streaming support and documentation gets better, this problem may resolve itself.

Comment: This question's likely to resolve itself, but this answer/discussion helped a lot, thanks.

Comment: i found some stream info in the manual actually. seems like it could help: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-streaming.html

Answer (score 1):

Craig the problem is that you use the Neo4j-Shell which is just an ops tool and just collects the data in memory before sending back, it was never meant to handle huge result sets.

You probably want to run your queries directly against the http endpoint with streaming enabled (`X-Stream:true` http-header) then you have no problem with that anymore.