# cypher query BadInputException

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In my graph there are approximately 196 000 C nodes, 600 000 A nodes, and 800 000 S nodes. 99% of C's are connected to a single A (with each A having anywhere from 0 - 20 Cs related), and all A's are connected to a single S.

I am running the following query

```
MATCH (c:C)<-[d:D]-(:A)<-[:u]-(s:S) 
WITH s, d, c, 
    CASE WHEN c.start - 1 - 20000 < 0 
    THEN 0 
    ELSE c.start - 1 - 20000 END AS start 
RETURN s.r, c.type, d.index, 
       substring(s.se, start, c.end-start + 1 + 20000);
```

It runs for around 2.5 hours, and then I get this response:

```
    {
  "message" : "The statement has been closed.",
  "exception" : "BadInputException",
  "fullname" : "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.BadInputException",
  "stacktrace" : [ "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.RepresentationExceptionHandlingIterable.exceptionOnHasNext(RepresentationExceptionHandlingIterable.java:50)", "org.neo4j.helpers.collection.ExceptionHandlingIterable$1.hasNext(ExceptionHandlingIterable.java:46)", "org.neo4j.helpers.collection.IteratorWrapper.hasNext(IteratorWrapper.java:42)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.ListRepresentation.serialize(ListRepresentation.java:71)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.Serializer.serialize(Serializer.java:75)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.MappingSerializer.putList(MappingSerializer.java:61)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.CypherResultRepresentation.serialize(CypherResultRepresentation.java:83)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.MappingRepresentation.serialize(MappingRepresentation.java:41)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.OutputFormat.assemble(OutputFormat.java:215)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.OutputFormat.formatRepresentation(OutputFormat.java:147)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.OutputFormat.response(OutputFormat.java:130)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.OutputFormat.ok(OutputFormat.java:67)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.web.CypherService.cypher(CypherService.java:101)", "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.TransactionalRequestDispatcher.dispatch(TransactionalRequestDispatcher.java:139)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.security.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:112)", "java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)" ],
  "cause" : {
    "message" : "The statement has been closed.",
    "exception" : "NotInTransactionException",
```

I am just running this query via curl as follows

```
curl -g -H Accept:application/json -H Content-Type:application/json -X POST  -d '{ "query":"MATCH (c:C)<-[d:D]-(:a)<-[:u]-(s:S) WITH s, d, c, CASE WHEN c.start - 1 - 20000 < 0 THEN 0 ELSE c.start - 1 - 20000 END AS start RETURN s.r, c.type, d.index, substring(s.se, start, c.end-start + 1 + 20000);", "params" : {} }'  localhost:7474/db/data/cypher -o data.json
```

I have added "limit 3;" to the query and it does run and return expected results.

Have I not properly optimized the query? I have read about query optimization and can't see anything I could improve on, although I bet there is. I can not find much documentation on solving that exception either.

Any help would be great! Thanks

Edit: fixed typo

Edit: I reran the same query with an additional "WHERE c.prop = 'x'" to limit the initial C matching and it then returned an OutOfMemory Exception. I then did some more reading and came across [this](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-streaming.html) from Michael's post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14855929/neo4j-outofmemory-error-when-querying). My query is now running and I think it is working. (There is a lot of data and it is downloading it to a file that is increasing in size.)

Answer (score 1):

So you're trying to match a LOT of different paths, and I think you probably are doing more computation than is necessary.  You might want to try this reformulation:

```
MATCH (c:C)
WITH c, CASE WHEN c.start - 20001 < 0
           THEN 0 ELSE c.start - 20001 as start
MATCH (c)<-[d:D]-(:A)<-[:u]-(s:S)
WITH c, start, s, d
RETURN s.r, c.type, d.index, substring(s.se, start, c.end - start + 20001);
```

My thought here is that you have the fewest number of `C`'s of any node.  So start the match there, and do your math computation first, then base subsequent matches off of that.  Otherwise you re-match `c` many extra times depending on how many of the other nodes there are.  You could further break this down based on the next-most-selective `A` with an additional `with` clause.  I think this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Which Neo4j version are you using?

I think you're creating billions and billions of paths.

To look at the cardinalities:

```
(c:C*196k)<-[d:D*1..20]-(:A*600k)<-[:u*1..1]-(s:S*800k)
```

**Profile your statement**, I think it makes sense to have it start from a `C` and follow the path to the single a and the single s from there.

so you can use `USING SCAN c:C` to force Cypher to scan the C nodes via the index which should give you 196k paths.

Each of those c-nodes would then be matched along the single-node-path.

So try @FrobberOfBits suggestion along with profiling and limiting the first `WITH` to see if the correct data is returned.

See: http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-using.html#using-hinting-a-label-scan